# Is it possible to move Notepad++ window while in Post-It mode?

Tags: notepad++

The border disappears and the window is always on top.
Is it possible to move it on the screen without exiting the Post-It  mode (<kbd>F12</kbd>)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. All handlers regarding the moving of a window are disabled for Notepad++ when it is in Post-It mode.

I tried the following tricks with no avail, and they're pretty deep, so if none of these work, it has been disabled programatically and thus it was designed to never be moved.

1. move the mouse over the taskbar, wait for the preview window to show, right click it and choose move. The move option here is not present.
2. Using the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> with optional shift modifier to move it that way or snap to the screen edge. Nothing happens.
3. I use a program called GRID Move. When holding the middle mouse button on any part of a program and moving the mouse, a grid shows up and based on where I move the mouse to, the window will be moved and sized according to this configuration. While in Post-it mode, the middle mouse button does not trigger the grid. Exiting the post-it mode, and everything works.

It is this last option that convinced me this is by design.

Comment: Just FYI you can also get the proper context menu by shift-rightclicking, rather than hovering over the preview and rightclicking.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to move NP++ while in Post-It mode. I had a good look through the documentation and the only mention of Post-It mode is how to enable it.

As Windows Snap or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> menu don't work with NP++ while in Post-It mode, I would guess that it was designed to be unmovable while in that state.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the post-it window using the third-party application AltMove: http://www.deskex.com/altmove/. You have to keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed and then drag the window with the mouse.

Comment: Cool program ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way: Just like feqwix said, you can use the tiny free utilities that allow you to grab a Window from anywhere. I use **AltDrag**: https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/
It has an installable and portable version, and it allows me to use a customizable modifier key (I just use Alt) to grab any Window from anywhere, and move it. It also comes with a few neat features. It's perfect in conjunction with the Notepad++ post-it mode.